# any sort of on resize bash event

Tags: bash

I have a sort of UI being made in a 'responsive' like manor, drawing a box at the bottom of the terminal using tput.

I was wondering if there is anyway to have it "redraw" the box when the terminal is resized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), the program which handles screen manipulation in linux (not bash!) sends a signal out when the window size is changed: `SIGWINCH` (window size changed). You'll want to handle the event and call a function to redraw your program when this event is received, which differs in implementation based on which programming language you're using. But for example, in C, it would be something like:

```
#include <signal.h>

void handleResize(int dummy)
{
     // redraw things here
}

int main(...)
{
signal(SIGWINCH, handleResize);
...
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to trap this event with bash, like this:

```
trap 'do something' SIGWINCH
```